# deleteOutputpath parameter is not considered in ng serve configuration

Tags: angular-cli

That prevents deleting my outDir when I run ng serve... directly in my Visual code editor in a terminal window:

```
ng serve --deleteOutputPath=false
```

But when I want to configure this call in the package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --deleteOutputPath=false",
    "build": "ng build",
  },
```

and just run

```
ng serve
```

in the terminal window then the outDir is deleted!

Why?

Comment: What version of the cli are you running? `--deleteOutputPath` isn't a valid options any more (with 1.5.2). `--delete-output-path` can be used with `ng build`. `ng serve` runs everything in memory.

Comment: angular cli 1.5.0

Answer (score -1):

To run the npm `start` script, you will need to run `npm start` or `npm run start`.

Also, if you never want the output directory removed for the project (including build and serve), you can run `ng set defaults.build.deleteOutputPath false` within the project.  Usage of the common line option will override the configured default.

Comment: pls refer to my question directly not some general information sharing...